# Custom json serializer for JSON column in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, json, serialization, sqlalchemy

I have following ORM object (simplified):

```py
import datetime as dt

from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Integer, Column, DateTime
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import JSONB
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session, declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class Metrics(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'metrics'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    ts = Column(DateTime, default=dt.datetime.now())
    computed_values = Column(JSONB)
    dates = Column(JSONB)


entry = Metrics(computed_values={'foo': 12.3, 'bar':45.6},
                dates=[dt.date.today()])

engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/my_schema')
with Session(engine, future=True) as session:
    session.add(entry)
    session.commit()
```

Each row has:

- `id` primary key
- `ts` timestamp when row was inserted
- `computed_values` actual JSONB data to be stored
- `dates` JSONB to store a list of dates for which the data was calculated.

While I have no issues with the `computed_values` column, the `datetime.date` objects in the list inside `dates` column cannot be serialized by default SQLAlchemy JSON serializer.

My thought is to redefine serializer behavior for `date` object for that exact column. To do that I have to either define my own custom JSON serializer, or use some ready-made one, like orjson. Since I'm likely to encounter many other JSON serialization issues on the project I'd prefer the latter.

Digging into the `JSONB` class and it's superclasses, I thought that following should do the trick:

```py
class Metrics(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'metrics'

    # ---%<--- snip ---%<---
    dates = Column(JSONB(json_serializer=lambda obj: orjson.dumps(obj, option=orjson.OPT_NAIVE_UTC)))

    # ---%<--- snip ---%<---
```

but it didn't:

```sh
File "metrics.py", line 30, in Metrics
    dates = Column(JSONB(json_serializer=lambda obj: orjson.dumps(obj, option=orjson.OPT_NAIVE_UTC)))
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'json_serializer'
```

What am I doing wrong and how to properly define custom SQLAlchemy serializer for JSON (and JSONB) Columns?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looks like you should be able to get what you want by modifying your `create_engine` statement.

From [the docstring in SQLAlchemy](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/json.py):

```
Custom serializers and deserializers are specified at the dialect level,
that is using :func:`_sa.create_engine`.  The reason for this is that when
using psycopg2, the DBAPI only allows serializers at the per-cursor
or per-connection level.   E.g.::
    engine = create_engine("postgresql://scott:tiger@localhost/test",
                            json_serializer=my_serialize_fn,
                            json_deserializer=my_deserialize_fn
                    )
```

So resulting code should be as following:

```py
import datetime as dt

import orjson

from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Integer, Column, DateTime
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import JSONB
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session, declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class Metrics(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'metrics'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    ts = Column(DateTime, default=dt.datetime.now())
    computed_values = Column(JSONB)
    dates = Column(JSONB)

entry = Metrics(computed_values={'foo': 12.3, 'bar':45.6},
                dates=[dt.date.today()])

def orjson_serializer(obj):
    """
        Note that `orjson.dumps()` return byte array, while sqlalchemy expects string, thus `decode()` call.
    """
    return orjson.dumps(obj, option=orjson.OPT_SERIALIZE_NUMPY | orjson.OPT_NAIVE_UTC).decode()


engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/my_schema',
    json_serializer=orjson_serializer,
    json_deserializer=orjson.loads)
with Session(engine, future=True) as session:
    session.add(entry)
    session.commit()
```

Comment: Yes, you're right! Found it myself digging deeper into docs. I'll edit your answer to solve possible problems with `orjson.dumps`